# How do I get a formula to read a cell range that is being spelled out by other formulas?

Tags: microsoft-excel

My ultimate goal is to determine the number of unique values associated with a specific name. Column A is the first column in a pivot table that has a list of names (some are listed multiple times). Column B is a list of values associated with the name. Column C is the left 2 numbers of column B. Column D is a list of the names (same as in A), but only listed once for each name. In Column E I want to know how many unique values in Column C are associated with each unique name in Column A, by referencing the unique name in Column D.

I can do this using a static range with the formula

```vbs
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(C7:C12,C7:C12))
```

I want my range to be dynamic so that when it references the name in Column D it creates the range of values for the same name in Column A, so that it knows what range in column C to count the number of unique values.

I have also been able to do this by using a MATCH formula to get the position of the first value:

```vbs
="C"&MATCH(D5,$A$1:$A$3879,0)
```

And a MAXIF formula to get the position of the last value:

```vb
="C"&MAX(INDEX(ROW($1:$3879)*($A$1:$A$3879=D5), , ))
```

Putting them together I can get the dynamic range that I want. In this example it is C7:C12.

My issue is inserting this dynamic range into my original formula. I was hoping I could insert them into my original formula and it would read it as a range.

```vb
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF("C"&MATCH(D5,$A$1:$A$3879,0)&":"&"C"&MAX(INDEX(ROW($1:$3879)*($A$1:$A$3879=D5), , )),"C"&MATCH(D5,$A$1:$A$3879,0)&":"&"C"&MAX(INDEX(ROW($1:$3879)*($A$1:$A$3879=D5), , ))))
```

This does not work. I have also tried using the text formula and the address formula to help create the range. Neither have worked.

Is there a way to get the SUMPRODUCT formula to read my match function and maxif function as  a range? Or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use INDEX:

```
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(D5,$A$1:$A$3879,0))
```

For the full range you would use:

```
INDEX(C:C,MATCH(D5,$A$1:$A$3879,0)):INDEX(C:C,MAX(INDEX(ROW($1:$3879)*($A$1:$A$3879=D5), , )))
```

So your SUMPRODUCT will be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(INDEX(C:C,MATCH(D5,$A$1:$A$3879,0)):INDEX(C:C,MAX(INDEX(ROW($1:$3879)*($A$1:$A$3879=D5), , ))),INDEX(C:C,MATCH(D5,$A$1:$A$3879,0)):INDEX(C:C,MAX(INDEX(ROW($1:$3879)*($A$1:$A$3879=D5), , )))))
```

But ultimately your Original formula can be simplified:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$3879=D5)/COUNTIFs($C$1:$C$3879,$C$1:$C$3879,$A$1:$A$3879,"<>"&D5))
```

Or with Excel 365 Excel

```
=ROWS(UNIQUE(TOCOL(FILTER($C$1:$C$3879,$A$1:$A$3879=D5)),3))
```

Comment: Those worked. Thank you!